# Click event on just highlight days in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I change the backgroud color of my highlight Days in datepicker with

```
beforeShowDay       : highlightDays, // it add a class name 'highlightdays'
```

It work good but Now I want to make some processing on these highlight Days when i click on them

I try the code below but it doesn't work

```
    $( ".highlightdays" ).click(function(e) {  
        //..
    } );
```

and i found that i have to use

```
onSelect            : afterclick
```

But here is my problem this function select all days even non highlight days !

Comment: have you put above function in `document.ready()` function ??

Comment: yes of course but this is not my problem i have no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3960ykdj/3/

```
 $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
        onSelect: function (dateString) {
            //string to date
            var date = new Date(dateString);
            //get day
            var d = date.getDate();
            //get TD which contains day as a string
            var $td = $('.ui-datepicker-calendar td a:contains("' + d + '")').parents('td');
            //if is highlightdays: do something
            if($td.hasClass('highlightdays'))            
                alert('do something');
        },
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var myDate = new Date(date);
            var d = date.getDate()
            var cls = '';
            if (d > 20 && d < 25) cls = 'highlightdays';

            return [true, cls, ''];
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you use `onSelect            : afterclick` with [event.currenttarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.currenttarget/) and [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) as below.
- Use

```
function afterclick(event){
    if(event.currentTarget.hasClass("highlightdays")){
        //  highlightdays Stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: that's the problem onSelect send just the date as argument not a event.